How to manage concurrent API token updates in a Python script using the same ini file for multiple clients?
I’m working on a Low-Level Discovery (LLD) script for Zabbix, which is set up as an "External" item. The script interacts with Aruba’s API to generate hosts for different clients based on their specific sites and devices.
The Aruba API requires authentication via access tokens, which expire after a set period. When the token expires, I need to refresh it using a refresh token. The challenge is that I manage API credentials for multiple clients (client ID, client secret, access token, and refresh token) in a shared .ini file.
The script is executed simultaneously for different clients, each accessing their own section in the .ini file. However, when the script runs concurrently (for example, for 5 clients at once), the tokens in the .ini file sometimes get lost or overwritten, leading to issues in API authentication.
Here’s what I’ve tried:

I implemented file locking using fcntl to prevent multiple processes from writing to the file at the same time.
Each client’s tokens are stored in a separate section of the .ini file, and each script execution is responsible for updating its own client’s section.
I expected file locking to prevent issues with tokens being overwritten, but despite using this approach, the tokens still sometimes get lost or corrupted when the script runs concurrently for multiple clients.

I expected the tokens to be safely updated and written to the .ini file without any loss or corruption, but the issue persists. How can I better handle concurrent updates to the .ini file to ensure tokens are updated correctly? Is there a better way to manage API tokens in this scenario?

Additional Information:
For anyone interested in reviewing the code, it’s available on my GitHub repository:
https://github.com/HorselessName/monitoramento-aruba


Why not just store tokens in one file per client, and avoid all the file contention issues?

In your code, you should acquire the lock before opening the file. Otherwise, other processes may already have successfully opened the file, which defeats the point of using a lock.

@larsks Yes, that would mitigate the problem but each client also executes and consults the same API multiple times because they have multiple services being monitored, I tested with only one client, it also happened (It was less frequent, but it happened.).
About your second answer: I implemented also a lock file before reading the file, as you can see in the line 380 of api_aruba.py source code in my GitHub. I think it's helping...
